# Restless vs. Dedicated Volunteers

Tags: word-choice

I'd like to learn whether it is fine to use `Restless` instead of `Dedicated` with a positive connotation to say that the volunteers are working very hard (or relentlessly) for a specific cause?

If I would use it in a sentence:

> X Institute is operating with the help of our restless volunteers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restless seems like it should mean 'without rest'. Instead, it means unable to rest or relax.
The better word would be tireless(it seems like it would mean 'without tires') which suggests that the volunteers will not grow tired.
'Dedicated' connotes devotion to the task more than the effort needed for the task.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that the word ***restless*** does not mean what you think it means.  Per the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[restless](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/restless)***
>
> **adjective**
>
> 1. Unable to rest or relax as a result of anxiety or boredom.
>
>    *‘the audience grew restless and inattentive’*
>
>    1.1 Offering no physical or emotional rest; involving constant activity.
>
>    *‘a restless night’*

You might actually be looking for ***tireless*** as Max K mentioned or you could mean ***relentless***.   The latter seems more likely, since you used its adverbial form in your question.  Per the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[relentless](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/relentless)***
>
> **adjective**
>
> 1. Unceasingly intense.
>
>    *‘the relentless heat of the desert’*
>
>    1.1 Harsh or inflexible.
>
>    *‘a patient but relentless taskmaster’*

In this case, you're probably looking at definition 1 which would indicate that your workers won't stop for anything.  So your sentence would be:

> *X Institute is operating with the help of our **relentless** volunteers.*